# Teradata SQL - Is it possible to list all matches from Where condition in same cell separated by a comma?

Tags: teradata

I am trying to get multiple PROCEDURE_CODE from the same VISIT_DATE into same cell on same row. This query just results 18 PROCEDURE_CODES when there should be 21 as three of the same VISIT_DATEs have two PROCEDURE_CODES. I am getting the first result and not both. The query I have is:

```
With Office_Visit as
(
SELECT 
TRIM(LEADING '-' FROM CAST(Pro_A.MEMBER_ID AS VARCHAR(20))) "MEMBER ID"
,Pro_A.VISIT_DATE "Date of Service"
,Pro_A.LOCATION Location
,row_number() over ( order by Pro_A.PROCEDURE_CODE ) as "Code(s)"

FROM CLAIMS.PROFESSIONAL Pro_A
)

SELECT
TRIM(LEADING '-' FROM CAST(Pro_B.MEMBER_ID AS VARCHAR(20))) "MEMBER ID"
,Pro_B.VISIT_DATE "Date of Service"
,Pro_B.LOCATION
,TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM (XMLAGG(TRIM(Pro_B.PROCEDURE_CODE)|| ',' ORDER BY Pro_B.VISIT_DATE) (VARCHAR(100)))) "Procedure Code(s)"
FROM CLAIMS.PROFESSIONAL Pro_B
WHERE
TRIM(LEADING '-' FROM CAST(Pro_B.MEMBER_ID AS VARCHAR(20))) = 'MEMBER001' 
AND Pro_B.LOCATION = 'OFFICE' 
AND Pro_B.PROCEDURE_CODE IN ('99201', '99202', '99203', '99204', '99205', '99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215', 
'99241', '99242', '99243', '99244', '99245', '99251', '99252', '99253', '99254', '99255', '99354', '99358', 
'99366', '99367', '99368', '99381', '99382', '99383', '99384', '99385', '99386', '99387', '99391', '99392', 
'99393', '99394', '99395', '99396', '99397', '99401', '99402', '99403', '99404', '99406', '99407', '99408', 
'99409', '99411', '99412', '99415', '99415', '99421', '99422', '99423', '99429', '99441', '99442', '99443', 
'99450', '99455', '99456', '99483', '99484', '99487', '99490', '99491', '99492', '99493', '99494', '99495', 
'99496', '99497', '99499') 
AND Pro_B.VISIT_DATE BETWEEN '2018-12-31' AND '2020-01-01'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

The results I would like to get is this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y19x3.png)

Thank you.

Comment: You must be using Teradata transaction semantics instead of ANSI. The result of XMLAGG is being CAST as VARCHAR(5) so the string is being truncated. (With ANSI semantics, it would fail with a string truncation error.)

Comment: Thank you. I caught that and changed it to VARCHAR(100) which shows multiple PROCEDURE_CODES, but it's also repeated the results multiple times because of the duplicates in the claim data. I am trying now to isolate it to distinct.

Comment: Thank you, @dnoeth. However, I am getting this error:  [Teradata Database] [6945] XML type argument is not compatible with TRIM() function now. I am working the Select to include the Office Visit CTE

Comment: Of course, your brackets are correct, sorry for the confusion. Based on Fred's comment your query should work now.

Comment: @dnoeth - Thank you. Yes, I can get the bottom statement to work (without the CTE), but I am struggling with working the DISTINCT piece in the CTE and adding it as a Select. Right now, I can get it all to run, but it repeats the same codes many times in the same cell and it is based on the number of times a record has been resubmitted or corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you want, the CTE prepares the data incl. DISTINCT and then you apply XMLAGG:

```
WITH Office_Visit AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
   Trim(Leading '-' FROM Cast(Pro_A.MEMBER_ID AS VARCHAR(20))) AS "MEMBER ID"
  ,Pro_A.VISIT_DATE AS "Date of Service"
  ,Pro_A.LOCATION AS Location
  ,Trim(Pro_A.PROCEDURE_CODE) AS PROCEDURE_CODE
FROM CLAIMS.PROFESSIONAL Pro_A
WHERE "MEMBER ID" = 'MEMBER001' 
  AND Pro_A.LOCATION = 'OFFICE' 
  AND Pro_A.PROCEDURE_CODE IN ('99201', '99202', '99203', '99204', '99205', '99211', '99212', '99213', '99214', '99215', 
    '99241', '99242', '99243', '99244', '99245', '99251', '99252', '99253', '99254', '99255', '99354', '99358', 
    '99366', '99367', '99368', '99381', '99382', '99383', '99384', '99385', '99386', '99387', '99391', '99392', 
    '99393', '99394', '99395', '99396', '99397', '99401', '99402', '99403', '99404', '99406', '99407', '99408', 
    '99409', '99411', '99412', '99415', '99415', '99421', '99422', '99423', '99429', '99441', '99442', '99443', 
    '99450', '99455', '99456', '99483', '99484', '99487', '99490', '99491', '99492', '99493', '99494', '99495', 
    '99496', '99497', '99499') 
  AND Pro_A.VISIT_DATE BETWEEN '2018-12-31' AND '2020-01-01'
)
SELECT
   "MEMBER ID"
  ,"Date of Service"
  ,LOCATION
  ,Trim(Trailing ',' FROM (XmlAgg(PROCEDURE_CODE|| ',' ORDER BY PROCEDURE_CODE) (VARCHAR(100)))) AS "Procedure Code(s)"
FROM Office_Visit 
GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: dnoeth - It worked PERFECTLY! I see what I was doing wrong. Declaring what needed to be done in the CTE and then using it in a clean query. Thank you so much! BTW, when I Google for Teradata tips, I see your posts and helps everywhere. I almost always get what I need from just reading the tips and replies especially from yours. Thank you again!

Comment: Thank you again, @dnoeth. Now, I need to join two related tables to the CTE in order to limit the data to be filtered for the end result. I need to join the 2019 membership roster to limit my data only to people who were active members in 2019 AND of those, only who had a hospital stay in 2019 which comes from the summary table. I tried to join all three tables using inner join on the Member IDs. I don't need any data from the hospital stay table, but just using it in the filter. Problem now is I am getting improper column reference no matter how I articulate it. I am posting it as a new ?

Comment: Figured it out. I had the tables listed in both the FROM and the INNER JOIN. I fixed it by removing two of the 3 tables from the FROM. Thanks again.